# Vuex: Can't change deeply nested state data inside actions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In the store, I have an action to update some data, the action looks like this:

```
setRoomImage({ state }, { room, index, subIndex, image }) {
      state.fullReport.rooms[room].items[index].items[subIndex].image = image;
      console.log(state.fullReport.rooms[room].items[index].items[subIndex])
    },
```

Because all of this data is dynamic so I have to dynamically change the nested values and can't directly hard code the properties. 
The data looks like this:

```
fullreport: {
    rooms: {
        abc: {
          items: [
            {
              type: "image-only",
              items: [
                {
                  label: "Main Image 1",
                  image: ""
                },
                {
                  label: "Main Image 2",
                  image: ""
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

When I dispatch the action, In the console I can see that the value of the sub-property `image` is successfully mutated, but if I access the VueX store from the Vue DevTools inside Chrome, I see that value doesn't change there. Here is the console output:

[image]

Please, can somebody tell why is it happening? As I know that data is successfully changing, but somehow the state isn't showing it and hence my components do not rerender.

I also tried using `Vue.set` instead of simple assignment, but still no luck :(

```
Vue.set(
  state.fullReport.rooms[room].items[index].items[subIndex],
  "image",
   image
 );
```

## Edit:

Following *David Gard's* answer, I tried the following:

I am also using Lodash `_` (I know making whole copies of objects isn't good), this is the mutation code block.

```
let fullReportCopy = _.cloneDeep(state.fullReport);
fullReportCopy.rooms[room].items[index].items[subIndex].image = image;
Vue.set(state, "fullReport", fullReportCopy);
```

Now In the computed property, where the `state.fullReport` is a dependency, I have a `console.log` which just prints out a string whenever the computed property is re-computed.

Every time I commit this mutation, I see the computed property logs the string, but the state it is receiving still doesn't change, I guess `Vue.set` just tells the computed property that the state is changed, but it doesn't actually change it. Hence there is no change in my component's UI.

Comment: Just btw: You should avoid having such large nested objects in the store. See https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143/6

Comment: Actually inside your action you should commit some mutation to do this

Comment: @MatheusValenza would that fix the current problem or just to follow the conventions?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Okay thanks! I'll normalize it.

Comment: @NadirAbbas actions doesn't update state. Mutations does. Probably you are getting some warning about this. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: @MatheusValenza I tried with the mutations, I don't get a warning anymore but still, the state doesn't seem to update, only in the console it shows the updated object.

Comment: did you try Vue.set instead of simple assign?

Comment: @MatheusValenza I simply assigned it just like I did it in the action, I edit my question

Comment: How are you using it in your components? I would guess it isn't updating properly after it's initially set. Is it a normal data() variable, or do you have a watcher/computed property built around it too?

Comment: @NickG Yeah it is a computed property

Answer (score 6):

#### As mentioned in comments - it quickly gets complicated if you hold deeply nested state in your store.

The issue is, that you have to fill Arrays and Objects in two different ways, hence, consider whether you need access to their native methods or not. Unfortunately Vuex does not support reactive Maps yet.

That aside, I also work with projects that require the dynamic setting of properties with multiple nested levels. One way to go about it is to recursively set each property.

### It's not pretty, but it works:

```
function createReactiveNestedObject(rootProp, object) {
// root is your rootProperty; e.g. state.fullReport
// object is the entire nested object you want to set

  let root = rootProp;
  const isArray = root instanceof Array;
  // you need to fill Arrays with native Array methods (.push())
  // and Object with Vue.set()

  Object.keys(object).forEach((key, i) => {
    if (object[key] instanceof Array) {
      createReactiveArray(isArray, root, key, object[key])
    } else if (object[key] instanceof Object) {
      createReactiveObject(isArray, root, key, object[key]);
    } else {
      setReactiveValue(isArray, root, key, object[key])
    }
  })
}

function createReactiveArray(isArray, root, key, values) {
  if (isArray) {
    root.push([]);
  } else {
    Vue.set(root, key, []);
  }
  fillArray(root[key], values)
}

function fillArray(rootArray, arrayElements) {
  arrayElements.forEach((element, i) => {
    if (element instanceof Array) {
      rootArray.push([])
    } else if (element instanceof Object) {
      rootArray.push({});
    } else {
      rootArray.push(element);
    }
    createReactiveNestedFilterObject(rootArray[i], element);
  })
}

function createReactiveObject(isArray, obj, key, values) {
  if (isArray) {
    obj.push({});
  } else {
    Vue.set(obj, key, {});
  }
  createReactiveNestedFilterObject(obj[key], values);
}

function setValue(isArray, obj, key, value) {
  if (isArray) {
    obj.push(value);
  } else {
    Vue.set(obj, key, value);
  }
}
```

#### If someone has a smarter way to do this I am very keen to hear it!

### Edit:

The way I use the above posted solution is like this:

```
// in store/actions.js

export const actions = {
  ...
  async prepareReactiveObject({ commit }, rawObject) {
    commit('CREATE_REACTIVE_OBJECT', rawObject);
  },
  ...
}
```

---

```
// in store/mutations.js
import { helper } from './helpers';

export const mutations = {
  ...
  CREATE_REACTIVE_OBJECT(state, rawObject) {
    helper.createReactiveNestedObject(state.rootProperty, rawObject);
  },
  ...
}
```

---

```
// in store/helper.js

// the above functions and

export const helper = {
  createReactiveNestedObject
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use it, but having trouble, It would be great if you can help me in using it in my code. How can I use this in the Store as action and these functions be local functions of an action?

Comment: @NadirAbbas I have updated my answer with some more implementation details, if you need further help let me know which errors you encounter. - Concerning the Edit in your question: it doesn't work because you need to recursively set properties as i wrote in my answer :)

Comment: This is actually not only not ugly, but it also makes it work the same way React, Redux, Snabbdom, Cycle, and other pure functional web frameworks work with immutable state. Coming from pure functional programming world, the discovery that Vue.js has this property patching fake reactivity based on ES6 Proxy all over the place was a big frustration to me personally...

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the good practices on the comments.

That you need is: to instruct Vue when the object change (Complex objects are not reactive). Use Vue.set. You need to set the entire object:

```
   Vue.set(
     state,
     "fullReport",
     state.fullReport
   );
```

Documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: Vue.set() adds reactive properties to an object. You cannot set a nested object with it. If you want to set a nested Object you need to recursively set each property.